# Сумма повторяющихся id mysql

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как у могу суммировать цену двух одинаковых id в запросе `IN`?

`select sum(price) FROM products WHERE id IN (1, 1)`

Comment: В такой форме - никак. Целевые значения id должны быть набором записей, а не списком значений.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(price) 
FROM products 
JOIN ( SELECT 1 id 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT 1 ) criteria USING (id)
```